# Can I use past tense and present tense in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, past-tense, grammaticality-in-context, present-tense

I'm doing my internal assessment for my geography and I'm confused whether what I wrote is grammatically correct. Here is the sentence:

> "China and the USA are two major countries that were chosen to be under the consideration of this internal assessment"

and I also have one more question, this one is for my English oral, I don't know if it's ok to say "the movie I chose is...... or do I have to say "the movie I choose is......". In both sentences, what's confusing me is I read in the grammar book that in one sentence I should have only one tense but my sentences also have the actions that already happened in the past so can someone please explain if two tenses can be mixed or not?

Comment: There's no special rule that says you have to use the same tense for all verbs in a sentence.  Often there is a natural time for the sentence, and the verbs naturally have the same tense.  Other times not.  Each clause can have different tense, and your mixed tense sentences here are fine.

Comment: Perhaps you could find the exact quote from the grammar book.  If the linked question doesn't help